# How to insert into table with max(ordering) + 1 in ordering column?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have a `chapters` table with a `ordering` column(integer) in Postgres. How to insert/create a new row with `ordering` set to `MAX(ordering) + 1` in diesel? I've tried using raw sql as following:

```
INSERT INTO chapters
(id, name, user_id, book_id, ordering, date_created, date_modified)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, IFNULL(MAX(ordering), 0) + 1, ?, ?
FROM chapters
WHERE book_id = ?;
```

and insert into by:

```rust
 let id = Uuid::new_v4().to_string_id();
    let now = Utc::now().naive_utc();
    diesel::sql_query(INSERT_CHAPTER)
        .bind::<Text, _>(&id)
        .bind::<Text, _>(name)
        .bind::<Text, _>(uid)
        .bind::<Text, _>(bid)
        .bind::<Timestamp, _>(&now)
        .bind::<Timestamp, _>(&now)
        .bind::<Text, _>(bid)
        .execute(conn)?;
```

It works on Sqlite3 backend, but fails on Pg backend with following error message:

```sh
"syntax error at or near \",\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$N` as placeholders for Postgres and `?` for sqlite3.